# Helm library chart returning can't evaluate field Values in type []interface {}

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm following the Helm Library chart example in the Helm docs [here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/#create-a-simple-library-chart).

The original example has a common ConfigMap in the library chart defined as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name | printf "%s-%s" .Chart.Name }}
data: {}
{{- end -}}
{{- define "mylibchart.configmap" -}}
{{- include "mylibchart.util.merge" (append . "mylibchart.configmap.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}}
```

I'm working on a chart that requires me to have an if statement to enable or disable a particular resource. In this  example, it's a configmap, but it could be an HPA or a deployment in a blue / green chart.

When I add the If statement as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name | printf "%s-%s" .Chart.Name }}
data: {}
{{- end -}}
{{- define "mylibchart.configmap" -}}
{{- if .Values.configMapEnabled }}
{{- include "mylibchart.util.merge" (append . "mylibchart.configmap.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

where `.Values.configMapEnabled` exists in the values.yaml file, and is set to `true`.

Everything else stays the same as described in the documentation i.e. I use a simple chart to include the library chart as a dependency, and I run:

`helm install mydemo mychart/ --debug --dry-run`

I am receiving the following error:

```
helm.go:84: [debug] template: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml:1:4: executing "mychart/templates/configmap.yaml" at <include "mylibchart.configmap" (list . "mychart.configmap")>: error calling include: template: mychart/charts/mylibchart/templates/_configmap.yaml:9:14: executing "mylibchart.configmap" at <.Values.configMapEnabled>: can't evaluate field Values in type []interface {}
```

Why isn't the Values field not being evaluated? It seems like a scoping issue, but I'm not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on my own setup and it looks like you didn't define ConfigMap in `lib Chart`.

Place it on the beginning of the file:

```
{{- define "mylibchart.configmap.tpl" -}}
```

Also in your case `lib Chart` doesn't know anything about `Values` - it is defined by `app Chart` side.
Also  all conditions should be placed in `app Chart` not `lib Chart`.

Schema:

```
parent/child chart -  chart dependencies, with global switches on/off
```

See section: [dependnecies -> condition: (optional)](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/%23the-chartyaml-file&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1594989928185000&usg=AFQjCNH9SFWPm_oAuqNSeCtth3Q0oU_WgA).

In your case:

```
$ helm install mydemo mychart/ --debug --dry-run --set configmap.enabled=false
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I should point out that I'm using Helm 3, so there is no Tiller. 

My question is regarding the use of an `if` statement when merging a chart template with a library template, rather than a straight out testing of a chart template. The `--debug --dry-run` is deliberate as I'm testing out the template rendering.

Comment: It is not problem with conditional statement but syntax mistake - try to apply `.Values.configMap.enabled`

Comment: It's not a syntax issue, it's related to the merge. I've tried exactly what you suggested, and I still receive the same error. Also for completeness, if I add the if statement to the beginning of the line, I get an error regarding an `unexpected <define> in command`